# Globalize Database ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, globalization

I would appreciate some thoughts here, we have globalized all the static content on the our site without issue but now we have come to the database content that users of the site can enter.  For example a user can create a survey with questions and answers and this needs to be globalized as well below is the way I have thought of doing it and the problems:

**Solution** - Separate tables for specific cultures, for example we have a `Survey` table with a name field, we move that name field to a `SurveyCultures` table which allows multiple name fields for each culture we want to support to be added against a survey. This would have to be done for the `SurveyQuestions` and `SurveyAnswers` table.  (this is the way it seems to have been done on the [MVC storefront example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-5-globalization))

**Problems** - This will create a lot of extra tables, one for every table that allows users to enter text that is visible to other users.  Also will create a very complicated front end allowing a user to enter the question, then select to enter the question for a different culture.  Also leads to problems if they only half translate a survey for a culture.

My question is: Is this the best way to go, is this the way people usually do it and if not what is the recommended practice for this that is usually undertaken?

Any feedback or thoughts would be greatly appreciated as I am going round in circles.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've little experience dealing with this issue, but the way I would approach it would be to add a "Language" column to existing tables. This might lead to something like:

```
Table: Survey
Columns: Unique identifier, date created, owner, etc.

Table: SurveyTitle
Columns: Language, Title, IsReleased (flag indicating whether survey in this language is ready for use), etc.

Table: SurveyQuestion
Columns: Language, QuestionNumber, QuestiontText etc.

Table: Language (this is a lookup table, used for foreign keys on all those Language columns)
Columns: Language (Id), Description, etc.
```

(All those etc. are fill-in for whatever you need that is specific to your requirements)
This way you have:

- A list of surveys
- A list languages that the survey is in (with flags for on/off, or ready/still being written)
- A list of questions in each language
- A list of all languages that are supported

Comment: I went with something very much along these lines as it gave me the most control.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Stick with your original tables. It's definitely not correct to add lots of tables. Nightmare to maintain and generally wrong.

In the relevant table(s) add a column (field) named `Locale`. It would contain for example: en-US, fr-FR, he-IL etc.

Then in your code, query this field and decide how to render your text or where to route it to. Same for inserts/updates.

You can, for example:

- Query all questions that are in a given language.
- Get a given question in all languages available.
- Save every data you have in every language you want, in the very same structure of tables and columns.

etc.